# Making an model inside of 2 ng-repeats accessible anywhere

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This content is all pulling from Firebase so it's not pre-defined (it's dynamic).

```
{{inputs.field[field.$id]}}
<div ng-repeat="field in fields | filter:{fieldID:field.$id}">
    {{field.label}}
    <div ng-repeat="choice in choices | filter:{fieldID:field.$id}">
        <input type="text" ng-model="inputs.field[field.$id]">
        {{inputs.field[field.$id]}}
    </div>
</div>
```

If you notice there is 2 places that I'm trying to display the `inputs.field[field.$id]` ng-model, inside of the ng-repeat and outside of it, it displays correctly inside but nothing shows up outside.

I tried the `$parent` call, but that only worked up one level (ex: `$parent.inputs.field[field.$id]`) I need a way to make the inner variables accessible everywhere (unlimited levels up) and accessible by the same variable name (yet also unique).

Comment: you can use $index

Comment: I tried `$index.inputs.field[field.$id]` and it didn't show up anywhere unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Declare variable at controller level in your JS.

Suppose you have `FireBaseCtrl` then first define `$scope.inputs = {}` in it.

And in your view use `FireBaseCtrl.inputs.field[field.$id]`

Comment: Is FireBaseCtrl the name of the controller?

Comment: FireBaseCtrl is your controllerAs (or you can say alias of your controller)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that items defined within an ng-repeat's scope will not be accesible outside the scope similar to how variables defined within a loop will not be accesible outside the loop. You're essentially trying to do this:

```
for (R in Looper) {
  //do something
}

alert(R);
```

On a side note, you can chain $parent.